Can the Turing machine be simplified while retaining Turing completeness?
When working on problems such as the Busy Beaver search, one quickly hits a combinatorial explosion of possible Turing machines, even for rather few states. Because of this and a drive for minimal systems, I'm wondering whether any features of the Turing machine are unnecessary.
The "basic" definition uses two symbols (0 and 1), with the tape initialised with 0s everywhere. Each state specifies what to do given finding 0 or 1: write 0/1, move left/right, change to another state.
The one thing that strikes me as potentially overpowered here is the ability to jump to any state. Let's define a simplified Turing machine with a circular order of states such that each state can only continue to the next/previous state (going before the first state moves the machine to the last state and vice versa). Is this limited programming system still Turing complete?
By Turing complete I mean precisely this: Instead of moving to an adjacent state, the machine can halt with accepting/rejecting its input. Then there must be an injective map $(T \times S) \mapsto (t \times s)$, with $T$ being the initial tape states of the basic Turing machine to initial tape states of the reduced Turing machine, $t$ the same for the reduced machine, $S$ the state configuration of the full machine and $s$ the state configuration of the reduced machine, that preserves the accepted/rejected tape states.
Initially, I thought it might be possible to simulate the full Turing machine by storing the desired state on the tape, but there doesn't seem to be any way to write it down.
In fact, there are only 16 possible different states (2 binary choices for each of 0 and 1), so a single state cannot store arbitrarily much information and we would have to rely on some combination of them to specify the end state. This makes the problem nonlocal in a way I don't know how to handle.
Another part of me says this is probably too weak. But OTOH, the global program behaviour depends on the order of states and the situation on the tape. It's somewhat reminiscent of cellular automata, which have local limited rules, but can still be Turing complete thanks to complex interactions between specifically designed board states.
I have no idea how to prove the system cannot do something.
Is there a simple reason one way or the other I'm overlooking?

You're looking for an alternative to a Turing machine with Busy Beaver numbers that grow slowly while still being Turing-complete? Since you can still simulate Turing machines that take a huge number of steps, so the only way to do this that I can see would be to write a definition where it requires astronomically large descriptions to simulate Turing machines. That would probably be much more complicated, not simpler, than the usual Turing machine.

By writing "next/previous", are you making an unstated assumption that the states are linearly ordered?

I suspect this version would still be Turing complete just because it seems hard to make a computer that isn't.  The way to prove it complete would be to show you can simulate a regular Turing machine.  This would require using some of the  tape to store the next state and reading it to get there.  It would expand the number of states.    One way to prove it not complete would be to show it can solve its halting problem. The Busy Beaver numbers would decrease as a function of the number of states but there would be fewer machines with a given number of states.

@LeeMosher, yes, or more precisely circularly ordered -- the next state of the last state is the first state and vice versa.

@JairTaylor, even a slight slowdown could dilute the problem enough to allow for some partial results. BB(5) is already too difficult for today's math, while BB(4) is manageable. If there were a rough correspondence like, say, BB(4) ≈ bb(12) and BB(5) ≈ bb(15) with bb being the Busy Beaver of the modified system, we would get two stepping stanes to work on in between. I don't expect this to be a big deal for research mathematicians, but for a mere interested layman, it would make the problem a lot more approachable.

To the 4 close voters requesting clarity: What exactly is unclear? Should I include the exact definition of a Turing machine?
